# Can I use $name instead of ${name}?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the sample [project](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#5).

I think I can use `${name}` instead of `$name` and `$name` instead of `${name}` just like Code B, is it right?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RallyNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Overview.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(Overview.name) {
            OverviewBody(
                onClickSeeAllAccounts = { navController.navigate(Accounts.name) },
                onClickSeeAllBills = { navController.navigate(Bills.name) },
                onAccountClick = { name ->
                    navController.navigate("${Accounts.name}/$name")
                },
            )
        }
        composable(Accounts.name) {
            AccountsBody(accounts = UserData.accounts) { name ->
                navController.navigate("Accounts/${name}")
            }
        }
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun RallyNavHost(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Overview.name,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        composable(Overview.name) {
            OverviewBody(
                onClickSeeAllAccounts = { navController.navigate(Accounts.name) },
                onClickSeeAllBills = { navController.navigate(Bills.name) },
                onAccountClick = { name ->
                    navController.navigate("${Accounts.name}/${name}")  //I changed
                },
            )
        }
        composable(Accounts.name) {
            AccountsBody(accounts = UserData.accounts) { name ->
                navController.navigate("Accounts/$name")    //I changed
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can

also read this article below:

kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-templates